# Convert into CNF form

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

How could I convert this into CNF? I'm stuck because I don't see anyway to add ANDs in here to get it in the proper from. Usually, I would use DeMorgan's or distribute, but that isn't an option here.

A ∨ B ∨ C

Comment: It's already in CNF.  Just one clause.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a way to change it to 2-CNF?